# How can an iptables 443 redirection on my host interfere with outbound HTTPS requests from my Docker container?

Tags: docker, iptables, docker-network

I recently diagnosed a very complex issue involving Docker and `iptables`.

I have an Ubuntu host with the following `iptables` settings:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat
[...]
Chain xyz (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* xyz */ redir ports 8443
```

The rule is in place to redirect all inbound traffic from port 443 to 8443. It is meant to redirect traffic to a Java-based application that has nothing to do with my Docker containers, but runs on the same machine, and has a self-signed SSL certificate.

When I run a Docker container on the same machine with Docker's default network settings, and I issue a wget HTTPS request from within the container, Docker (or the OS) seems to redirect the outbound connection to port 8443 on the Ubuntu host, and, therefore, to the local Java-based application which, in turn, accepts the connection (most of the times) and returns invalid (self-signed) certificate details. As a result, applications inside the container end up talking to this local Java application on the host, instead of the real servers on the Internet they should be talking to.

I also verified that any wget HTTPS request issued directly from the Ubuntu host hits the target server on the Internet. The problem occurs only with requests that are initiated by Docker containers running on the same host.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

The example is not complete. You have not shown where this chain is linked from. I'll try to answer anyways, but you might want to reduce your IPtables rules to a set that does nothing but reproduce your problem.

The way iptables works is that the incoming packet has matching rules applied to it. Any rule that matches it, has its target applied.

In your case, what probably happens is that your outbound packets are matched on this rule, and therefor get redirected as well.

Since REDIRECT targets are on the pre-routing table, and that one is not limited to incoming traffic, you will need to limit the matching in some way. Easiest, probably, is to add `! -i lo` to the rule. This should prevent matching of packets arriving through the loopback interface.